# how to calculate the duration using a date - angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5, angular7

Api ,

```
{
   data:{
      "duration": 12,
      "startDate": "27-01-2020 16:09"
   }
}
```

I am using angular 2+..I api, duration is 12( in month) and given the startdate...

Task:-

I have to calculate the expiring days(license is expiring in DD days). So have to subtract the today's date from startDate(in api)..

Can anybody help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which specific bit are you struggling with?

Comment: @AngelReji use moment date diff follow this link https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
data = {
  data: {
    "duration": 12,
    "startDate": "27-01-2020 16:09"
  }
};

var date1 = new Date();

var nDate = String(data.data.startDate);
var onlyDate = nDate.split(" ");

var dParts = onlyDate[0].split("-");

var date2 = new Date(dParts[2] + '-' + dParts[1] + "-" + dParts[0]);
console.log(date1);
console.log(date2);
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
console.log(diffDays);
```

My [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michastg29/o25v1kns/13/)

Comment: but the date format is "startDate": "27-01-2020 16:09"

Comment: facing problem  by the date format...can you help me??

Comment: see parsed date obove